# What would it take to create a simple multiplayer javascript game?

Tags: javascript, multiplayer

I want to keep it really simple at first. Basically allow two people to move two squares around with arrow keys and maybe have them detect when they hit each other.

Comment: It takes some efforts to write the code. That's your starting point. [Stack Overflow is not a Code Writing, Tutorial or Consulting Service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/102937)

Comment: I have tried nothing yet other than writing the code for moving a square around. I don't want someone to write the code for me, I just want to know where to start.

Comment: you can use nodejs and socket.io for socket connections between several clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the most abstract way possible:

You're going to need some kind of central point for the different players to talk to unless you also want to be writing some kind of distributed networking code (hint: you don't.)

Just about any kind of 'server' will do for this.  The sever will let the players talk to each other.

Once you get the messages flowing between the users, then you'll need to figure out what to do with them.

If I were you I'd go lookup some kind of basic chat room software, there's loads out there, it will show you a way to do the message passing.  Then maybe try seeing if there isn't some way you could build a game on top of that.